# Symfony 2 AvalancheImagineBundle image filter

Tags: php, symfony, twig

input:

```
{% for car in closet %}
<img src="{{ asset('images/') }}{{ car.photo1 }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

html output:

```
<img src="/images/1bb8cee7cd58403ba84daee67d82fa869ec6052d.jpeg" />
```

How can I apply this from AvalancheImagineBundle:

```
<img src="{{ '/relative/path/to/image.jpg' | apply_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

I can't get this working because the path and filename are separated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

`<img src="{{ (asset('images/') ~ car.photo1) | apply_filter('my_thumb') }}" />`